# Make two agents follow the same random number stream

Tags: anylogic

So I have two agents, "Agent1" and "Agent2" both inheriting a statechart from the mother class "MotherAgent":

[image]

- In the transition from "normal" to "down" I have added *exponential() * 5 days*
- In the transition from "down" to "normal" I have added 1 day.

When I run the simulation, I see that "agent1" and "agent2" do not make transitions at the same time.

The end goal is to make the two agents have the exact same transitions (they move to "normal" at the same time, and they move to "down" at the same time)

How can this be achieved? I am open to other modelling approaches if they fit the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's better to coordinate the transitions separately, using an event for example, and when the event is triggered, all the agents are sent a message that will trigger the transition.

Comment: Thanks, that approach seemed to work. I'm a bit annoyed that I had to send the message to all the agents and not only the mother class. Any idea why that is? :)

Comment: messages are always send to individual agents, you cannot send messages to classes (this is not a flaw and not an AnyLogic issue but fundamentally how OOP works :) )